# Disable the 'save image' menu on iPhone with Javascript

Tags: iphone

Have a photography site that I want to prevent image copying from.  How can I disable the save image menu that pops up on an iPhone when you hold down your finger on an image?

Comment: I assume you have this same problem in the right-click context menu on a desktop browser? Sites like Flickr and others will often cover the `img` object in the DOM with an invisible `div`, or something to that effect.

Comment: No, we have the right-click context menu disabled already, but need something to target the touch event separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';
```

As an aside is it really worth it? Hacks like this do impact user expectations, and your image is on the internet, anyone who wants it can easily get it regardless of whether a context menu has been disabled in the browser they're using.

Comment: I agree to a point, but the key word is 'easy'.  I think disabling the menu, just as with a desktop browser, effectively makes downloading images difficult FOR THE AVERAGE visitor.  It's still easy for me, but not for some mom trying to download images of her kid :)

Comment: Why are you trying to stop mums downloading pictures of their kids? You monster!. j/k. I take your point - easy is a relative term. I'm not convinced it's worth implementing, but it's not my site or userbase :). did the webkitTouchCallout work for you btw?

Comment: You can also apply it in the CSS: `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution with CSS (`-webkit-touch-callout: none;`) as @alex tells, works fine with iOS7 Safari. Thanks.